# Flash: automatic/infinite/horizontal slider

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, flash-cs5

What I want to do is actually quite simple :p

I have a couple of (let's say 10) pictures (photographs actually) that should automatically scroll from right to left in a 500x500px container. In an infinite loop. So all the pics are horizontally next to each other, each 500px of height, variable width.

That's not all unfortunately... Some pictures need to be animated, i.e. a simple sequence of like 2-3 pictures.
That means we now have pictures and animations sliding through a 500x500 frame from right to left. The animations should simply switch pictures every ~1-2 seconds, which should be easy with Flash.

Unfortunately I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Flash.
Could someone please help me out here? Maybe a tutorial or even a smallish example .fla?

Thanks so much in advance!

(Oh my Flash version is CS5)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to do this programmatically, but as you are "a complete newbie", you are probably better off using the timeline for now.

Here is how you might like to approach it:

- import all your images to the library
- create a graphic for each image
- create a movieclip from each graphic which is not part of an animation
- create one movieclip, to hold the animated images, for each animated set, putting the images ontop of each other on separate layers and tween the alpha of them over time, revealling the next image below.
- create another movieclip and place all the previously created movieclips next to each other within it
- create one more movieclip and place two instances of the above movieclip alongside each other
- add this final movieclip to the stage and tween from right to left making sure that the
  final frame of the tween looks the same as the first frame.